# Add extension methods to specific instantiations of unknown class that implements a known interface

Tags: c#

I am using a library called SpreadsheetGear. With this I work with "IWorkbook" objects that I initialize by a method SpreadsheetGear.Factory.GetWorkbook() whose contract returns an IWorkbook.

I want to <strike>derive</strike> **implement** an interface and write extension methods, for example I define

```
 public partial interface IClientWorkbook : IWorkbook
```

so I can do something like

```
 IClientWorkbook workbook = SpreadsheetGear.Factory.GetWorkbook;
 workbook.ChangeClientName("NewName");
```

and define the ChangeClientName method somewhere else, but not have it available to IWorkbooks that aren't IClientWorkbook.

I'm not sure how to approach this as can't see the actual class that the GetWorkbook() method returns. Hopefully the question makes sense.

Comment: See how I changed your original markdown... Don't use `<br>`, markdown turns new lines as `<br>` when they're converted into HTML.

Comment: Also, you **implement** interfaces instead of *deriving* them.

Comment: If `GetWorkbook` returns `IWorkbook` then you cannot assign it to the more derived `IClientWorkbook`.  Are you sure you don't just want to create your extension methods on `IWorkbook` instead?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your question, you want to define a custom interface (IClientWorkbook) that you then want to be implemented by objects returned from a 3rd-party API. You cannot do this. You can implement extension methods for the existing class or interface, but you cannot add a new interface to an existing class without editing the code for that class. Also, you cannot create an extension method that doesn't apply to all instances of the extended type. That is, you cannot create an extension method that only applies to some IWorkbook instances -- you either don't have an extension method, or you have an extension method that applies to all IWorkbook instances.

You could write wrapper classes for all the bits of the 3rd-party API, and you can then implement your classes however you choose. This is sometimes worth it, but more often not.

Comment: +1 on wrapper class.  But if you do this, you don't need an extension method, it can just be a method of your wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

It must be as easy as

```
public static class ClientWorkbookExtensions {
    public static void ChangeClientName(this IClientWorkbook workbook, String newName) {
        workbook.Name = newName;    //  Or any other code you like
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the quest more thoroughly, op doesn't have access to the type being returned from GetWorkbook and therefor cannot implement the IClientWorkbook interface.

Comment: How does that makes my solution wrong? It **does not** make any implication on the **real** type of the IClientWorkbook, it only requires that type implements IClientWorkbook, that's all.

Comment: Your not wrong, if the question was "How do I implement an extension method?".  Unfortunately your solution did not address the root of the ops problem.

Comment: Well, that depends on how the interfaces are defined, which is not known.